# Create multiple collection Mongoose name based on JSON

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have JSON data like this:

```
[
    { "name": "Algeria", "flag": "Algeria.png", "confederation": "CAF", "rank": 21 },
    { "name": "Argentina", "flag": "Argentina.png", "confederation": "CONMEBOL", "rank": 5 },
    { "name": "Australia", "flag": "Australia.png", "confederation": "AFC", "rank": 32 },
    { "name": "Belgium", "flag": "Belgium.png", "confederation": "UEFA", "rank": 11 },
    { "name": "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "flag": "Bosnia-and-Herzegovina.png", "confederation": "UEFA", "rank": 20 }
]
```

I want to create multiple collection based on "name" if I input that JSON. Is that possible to do in Mongoose Node.js?

Thanks

Comment: One collection for each name? I guess you mean one document per name.

Comment: yes you right, one collection for each name...

Comment: like one table for each name in MySql

Comment: Why would you do that? A table/collection each for Algeria, Argentina, Australia and the rest of the countries. That's 200+ collections right there. The conventional approach that makes sense is to have one collection `countries` and have one document representing each country.

Comment: I don't know your actual requirement but you probably should reassess your suggested way of tackling the issue.

Comment: Thanks you for your suggestions